# How to scroll FlatList in Modal component?

Tags: react-native

My Horizontal FlatList doesn't scroll in Modals. You can find my FlatList and RenderItem codes below:

```
    <FlatList
        data={this.props.selectedGroupData.groupMembersList}
        renderItem={this.ilgiliKisiler}
        keyExtractor={item => item.uid}
        nestedScrollEnabled={true}
        horizontal={true}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        />

    </View>
```

and renderItem function:

```
    ilgiliKisiler = ({ item }) => {
    console.log("on Related Users item => ", item);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <View style={styles.relatedUsersContainer}>
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
              <Image
                source={
                  item.avatar
                    ? { uri: item.avatar }
                    : require("../../assets/images/defaultAvatar.png")
                }
                style={styles.relatedUsersImage}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
              <Text style={styles.relatedUsersText} numberOfLines={2}>
                {item.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

Before this post, i found some solutions like `style={{flex: 1}}`. When i try to this solutions, my renderItem doesn't appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `propagateSwipe` props for smooth scrolling in `<Modal>`

```
<Modal propagateSwipe>...</Modal>
```

for more detail [react-native-modal issue #236](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/issues/236)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting this as an answer, but I can't comment because of my low reputation. I'll remove this answer if it doesn't work for you.

Have you tried using `contentContainerStyle` on your FlatList like so:

```
contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
```

You can read more about `contentContainerStyle` at this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle

Comment: Sorry, It's not a correct answer. It doesn't matter to use `style:{{ flex: 1 }}` in your `<View>` component. But, thank you for effort and reply. I found correct answer and posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Flatlist inside a scrollview. It should work.

```
<Scrollview>
<Flatlist />
</Scrollview>
```